# I screwed up ubuntu on a dual boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I essentially destroyed my Ubuntu 16.04 version when I was trying to delete files that were "sudo" restricted but ended up doing a lot more damage than that. Needless to say, I couldn't even open a terminal up after I stopped it although I was able to save my data (phew!). I am on a dual boot system however and when I restarted my computer, it went straight to rescue grub. How can I get to Windows 7? This is what I see:

```
Error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found

Entering rescue mode

Grub rescue
```

THanks

Comment: go into system settings or boot options. see if you system supports booting by OS. (most do now)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not exactly sure how to do that from where I am. Can you please point me towards a tutorial or something?

Comment: hold down a function key while booting, it varies by computer .... F2, F10, and F12 are common but could be any one

Comment: possible dublicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71555/boot-windows-from-grub-rescue-command-prompt)

Comment: @derHugo you can't tell that is a duplicate from another stack exange site

Comment: The `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` file is used only on BIOS-boot systems, so ravery's suggestion (which would be good for EFI-based systems) likely won't work. Instead, please see v_sukt's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get to windows you have two ways.

- Using ubuntu rescue CD - rescue mode

  - here you can grub-install to the head of the drive you have installed it on
  - check windows - part of grub menu - its loaded via chainloader
- Using windows bootable DVD - rescue mode

  - reach the command prompt
  - type `fixmbr (device-name)` e.g. `\Device\HardDisk0` or just execute `fixmbr` without any argument
  - or you can do  `bootrec /fixboot and bootrec /fixmbr` , in this method you'll get windows back then you can try ubuntu rescue cd and repair installed OS in its install mode

Comment: OK. I am at the command prompt for windows. I run start up repair it shows an error and session details show this: System Dick = \Device\Harddisk0; Windows Directory = ; AutoChk Run = 0; Number of root causes = 1. At the very bottom it says Root cause found: No OS files found on disk. Repair action: partition table repair; Result: Failed. Error code = 0x2bc3.

Comment: try testdisk and read partition table-write it. then try https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/partition-repair-startup-repair-failed-error-code/3af92d1a-e7ef-451d-9adc-3f7ffe8bb9c4